# Two boxes side by side

Tags: css, image, positioning

I have thrown a quick example in jsfiddle to show you what is happening and then I will explain what I want to achieve..

http://jsfiddle.net/4UMLq/20/

(code html - in jsfiddle)

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box1top">
    </div>
    <div class="box1middle">
        <p> Test </p><br />
        <p> Test </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box1bottom">
    </div>
        <div class="box1top">
    </div>
    <div class="box1middle">
        <p> Test </p><br />
        <p> Test </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box1bottom">
    </div>
</body>
</html>​
```

(code css - in jsfiddle)

```
.box1top {
    width: 150px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#373737;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-top:10px;
}
.box1middle {
    width: 150px;    
    height:200px;
    background-color:#676767;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
.box1bottom {
    width: 150px;
    height:10px;
    background-color:#373737;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
.box2top {
    width: 150px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#373737;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
.box2middle {
    width: 150px;    
    height:200px;
    background-color:#676767;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
.box2bottom {
    width: 150px;
    height:10px;
    background-color:#373737;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

In the example above the bg colours are going to be images for boxes that will contain text (split into 3 images)

However I want to display these side by side in the browser window instead of underneath one another.. I have tried floating the elements ect and I just cant seem to get this right?

Has anyone got any ideas? Any help is appreciated

Thanks,
Carlos

Comment: have you tried `display:inline` or `display:table-cell` ?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/4UMLq/21/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general principle when coding (anything) is to keep it DRY (don't repeat yourself).

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/4UMLq/21/

Luckily, CSS allows us to accomplish this easily:

```
.box{
    float:left;
    margin:10px 10px 0 10px;
    width: 150px;
}

.box-top {
    height:30px;
    background-color:#373737;
}
.box-middle {   
    height:200px;
    background-color:#676767;
}
.box-bottom {
    height:10px;
    background-color:#373737;
}

#box2{
    margin-left:0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="box1" class="box">
    <div class="box-top">
    </div>
    <div class="box-middle">
        <p> Test </p>
        <p> Test </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-bottom">
    </div>
</div>    
<div id="box2" class="box">
    <div class="box-top">
    </div>
    <div class="box-middle">
        <p> Test </p>
        <p> Test </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-bottom">
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that the top, middle, and bottom divs are each nested inside of a "box" div. There is no reason to create duplicate `boxNtop`, etc CSS definitions, because many elements may share the same class name. So, if you want them all to look the same, it is easily done.

Comment: So simple.. Thanks for the help and adding more advice regarding keeping it DRY, that's great!. I find it easy to layout with tables but i'm trying to move away from that..

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this, but I think you'll want to start with wrapping those boxes within something you can float, such as: http://jsfiddle.net/wKqnh/

HTML:

```
<div class="box-wrap">
    <div class="box1top">
    </div>
    <div class="box1middle">
        <p> Test </p><br />
        <p> Test </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box1bottom">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box-wrap {
    float: left;
}
```

This has some other layout consequences, so for example, anything after the boxes will be aligned to the left of the last box depending on how their container is sized.

Here's a good article on basics to float based layouts: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-floats-101/

Comment: Thanks for the link to the article. Will help me going forward!